# AutoSitemap extension notice after moving or deletion pages

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm using MediaWiki `v1.34.0` and installed AutoSitemap extension (`v1.4`) on my Wiki and each time I move or delete pages this notice comes up at the top of the page:

```
"Notice: Only variables should be assigned by reference in 
 /extensions/AutoSitemap/AutoSitemap_body.php on line 122.
```

I went to look inside the said file and on line `122` I have `$dbr =& wfGetDB(DB_REPLICA);`

And I have the following code in my `LocalSetting.php` file:

```
    wfLoadExtension( 'AutoSitemap' );
    $wgAutoSitemap["freq"] = "daily";
    $wgAutoSitemap["priority"] = 1;
```

Product Versions:

```
> MediaWiki 1.34.0<br> PHP  7.2.30 (cgi-fcgi)<br> MySQL 5.7.28-log<br>
> ICU   60.2
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? This looks like a bug in either MediaWiki or the extension you are using

Comment: I just followed the suggestion by Alexander Mashin below and removed the ampersand in my AutoSitemap_body.php and it's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you:

- file an issue with the extension (https://github.com/dolfinus/AutoSitemap/issues/new/choose), since it is still maintained, because it is easily corrected (see below),
- meanwhile, just delete that ampersand. It is not needed since PHP 5.

Comment: Alexander Mashin, thank you for your suggestion. I removed that ampersand and guess what? that notice stopped coming up so looks like that was the only reason why I was seeing that notice. Thanks a lot.